# Custom UISlider - problems in iOS5

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, uislider

UISlider looks as i want in iOS6, but not in iOS5.

I want to make custom UISlider, and for this purpose i made a subclass of UISlder, in which i put:

```
   [self setThumbImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [self setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"fast_dots"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [self setMaximumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"fast_dots_white"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

`[UIImage imageNamed:@"fast_dots"]` is:[image]

`[UIImage imageNamed:@"fast_dots_white"]` is: [image]

This way my UISlider looks in iOS6:[image]

This way my UISlider looks in iOS5: [image]

I have tried all variations of resizableImageWithCapInsets, but nothing help.

Comment: Did you try a non-zero edge inset?

Comment: You sure it's an iOS5 vs iOS6 issue, and not a retina vs. non-retina issue? Have you tried adding a @2x image?

Comment: It is not retina - non-retina issue. It is io5 -ios6 issue for sure (my screenshots were made on retina). I have tried all variations of edge insets. Looking on my screenshots, i thing, that in ios5 images not repeated, but scaled. And i have no idea^ how to deal with this oddity